# How to handle memory error on book.parse(sheet)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

## Getting a memory error  on book.parse(sheet)

I am getting a memory error after reading a few files in the directory on `book.parse(sheet)`

```
for filename in os.listdir(cwd):
        if filename.endswith('.xlsx') and not filename.startswith(('1Data')):
            book = pd.ExcelFile(filename)
            print(filename)
            for sheet in book.sheet_names:
                df = book.parse(sheet) #how can i handle this 
                if 'comp' in df.columns:
                    df['comp1']=df['comp']
                    print("For "+filename+"\n")
                    book2=df.pivot_table(values='comp1',index=['pe','id'], columns='comp', aggfunc='count',margins=True)
```

Comment: How big is the .xlsx file? what RAM does your PC have? What memory allocation do you have for Python? You can always split the file...

Comment: ram of my pc is 16 gb and i have 5 file of  199mb around

Comment: can you help me with this code

Comment: or there is any other way to do it i am struggling

Comment: you can try to read the files with pandas: https://pythonspot.com/read-excel-with-pandas/ For the code you have you'd have to reserach with the function and the package code to understand the limitations. I don't know what import package you use. Or here another option: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-excel-file-using-python/